# What is Travis.yml in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

What is Travis.yml file in Codeigniter . Why we need this ?

In case i remove it from Codeigniter Package then what will happen ?

Immediate reply highly appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Travis CI uses .travis.yml file in the root of your repository to learn about your project and how you want your builds to be executed.

[Further reading](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#.travis.yml-file%3A-what-it-is-and-how-it-is-used)